# Change the way a DataProperty displayName is looked up in a Validator in Breeze

Tags: breeze

In the Validator class, the rootContext has a displayName function that is used to find the display name when constructing the validation error message. I'm storing user-friendly display names in the custom properties object of all my DataProperty's, so I'd like that displayName function to look in that area before any other area. As far as I can tell there is no way to override the rootContext from the Validator class in order to change it there. And the only other way I can think to do it would be to pass in a new displayName function in the context when I'm constructing the Validators, but in order to do that I'd have to write a custom metadata parser, unless I'm missing something there. Do you guys have a suggested way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is good question.  This is NOT well documented but ... for the time being I would just copy the value resulting from executing your custom displayName function directly onto the 'displayName' property of the corresponding DataProperty or NavigationProperty immediately after querying your metadata. We will be documenting the 'displayName' property in the next release but it is available now.

The subject of improving 'displayName' discovery process is something that is on our plate but we just haven't gotten to it yet.

Comment: This worked for me and I implemented it. As our application has a lot of different entity types with lots of data properties and navigation properties, it's not ideal. It would be nice to have a way to extend the rootContext that Breeze gives to all the Validators . The other thing it looked like I could do is override the metadata parsing in order to change the context passed into the Validators, but that seemed like overkill